# Symfony2 ACL - isGranted always returns false

Tags: php, symfony, acl

I've spent a few hours already trying to make Symfony's ACL working in my project but I'm simply not able to find a solution. This is my testing example:

```
$competition = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
    ->getRepository('MyBundle:Competition')->find(158);

$objectIdentity = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($competition);
$aclProvider = $this->get('security.acl.provider');
try {
    $acl = $aclProvider->findAcl($objectIdentity);
} catch (\Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Exception\AclNotFoundException $e) {
    $acl = $aclProvider->createAcl($objectIdentity);
}

// retrieving the security identity of the currently logged-in user
$securityIdentity = UserSecurityIdentity::fromAccount(
        $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser());

// grant owner access
$acl->insertObjectAce($securityIdentity, MaskBuilder::MASK_EDIT);
$aclProvider->updateAcl($acl);
```

.

```
$competition = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
    ->getRepository('MyBundle:Competition')->find(158);

$foo = $this->get('security.context')->isGranted(MaskBuilder::MASK_EDIT, $competition);

var_dump($foo); // always bool(false)
```

I can see data showing up in the tables but `isGranted` always returns false. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

**acl_classes**:

```
id  class_type
2   Me\MyBundle\Entity\Competition
```

**acl_entries**:

```
id  class_id    object_identity_id  security_identity_id    field_name  ace_order   mask    granting    granting_strategy   audit_success   audit_failure
1   2           3                   2                       NULL        0           4       1           all                 0               0
```

**acl_object_identities**:

```
id  parent_object_identity_id   class_id    object_identifier   entries_inheriting
3   NULL                        2           158                 1
```

**acl_object_identity_ancestors**:

```
object_identity_id  ancestor_id
3                   3
```

**acl_security_identities**:

```
id  identifier                  username
2   Me\MyBundle\Entity\User-Me  1
```

Comment: can you try to pass `'EDIT'` instead `MaskBuilder::MASK_EDIT`?

Comment: i mean `$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('EDIT', $competition);`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my entity which implements ObjectIdentityInterface...

My implementation of getType was:

```
public function getType() {
      return __CLASS__;
}
```

this was returning the name of the class where it was declared(static), and fails in the comparisson

so i changed it to dinamically:

```
public function getType() {
      return get_class($this);
}
```

hope it helps